# ServletRegistrationBean not working with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to register servlets using `ServletRegistrationBean` in Spring (not Spring Boot) using following code:

```
@configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> customServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CustomServlet(), "/custom");
        bean.setLoadOnStartUp(1);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I have confirmed the bean is being created, and the servlet `CustomServlet` is not registered. BTW,  the web.xml registers some other servlets and they are fully functional.

What could be the cause of this?

- `ServletRegistrationBean` can only work with Spring Boot?
- `ServletRegistrationBean` cannot mix with web.xml?
- I missed something?

I googled this but couldn't find any related question.

Comment: The fact that you are using a `web.xml` is already telling enough. The `ServletRegistrationBean` works only with Spring Boot in charge of bootstrapping the application. Apparently you aren't doing that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for replying. Does that means there is no way to register servlets with `ServletRegistrationBean` in Spring?

Comment: Not without spring boot.